# EOL converter as a shell extension

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I'm looking for a EOL converter for Windows with Explorer integration so that I can simply right-click on a file and select which type of line-ending I want to convert to. I often run into files which have inconsistent line-endings, and Subversion refuses and commit those until I fix them.

Comment: Would you mind to share a sample file? This way I can test some solutions easier.

Comment: Here's a file with mixed line-endings: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2113034/crlf.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this solution you can right click any file and convert from `LF` (Unix, Linux, Mac OS X) to `CR+LF` (Windows)  line breaks

1. Create a .CMD file somewhere and paste the following code

   ```
   SET "output=%~1"
   SET "search=\%~n1."
   SET "replace=\%~n1 (CR+LF)."        
   CALL SET "output=%%output:%search%=%replace%%%"

   TYPE "%~1" | FIND "" /V > "%output%"
   ```

   Line 1-4 are only for renaming the output file correctly and append "(CR+LF)" to the filename
   You can read more about [batch arguments](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true) here.
   The key is that `TYPE` knows [how to read LF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110031/batch-file-convert-lf-to-crlf) line endings
2. Save a shortcut from the .CMD file in your *sendto* folder (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> » shell:sendto )

For additional conversion directions, download the command line utility [dos2unix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/?source=dlp) and use it the same way as shown above. Just replace the last line. The syntax is always the same.

```
dos2unix "%~1" "%output%"
mac2unix "%~1" "%output%"  
unix2dos "%~1" "%output%"  
unix2mac "%~1" "%output%"
```

---

Notepad++ has a handy EOL conversion option but I guess you already know that and it is not comfortable and fast enough to open, convert and save the file. Unfortunately notepad++ doesn't provide command line switches for that specific task.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately Notepad++ cannot convert files with mixed line-endings. If there are both LF and CRLF in a file, it will refuse to directly convert to Windows. You have to first convert to Unix, and then back to Windows. Annoying.

Comment: I opted for the "unix2dos" variant. The "TYPE" variant didn't work. Will it correctly detect file with mixed EOL conventions?

Comment: Hmm, I tested the TYPE method in just this second with your test file. It worked pretty well. Here is a [proof screen for the TYPE method](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bp1B2.png)

Comment: I am curious about what went wrong in your test setup. I can't reproduce your behavior. Can you explain it more?

Comment: Maybe, if I can squeeze in some time to experiment a little. Is there a way to keep the cmd window open after the command finishes?

Comment: Just add *pause* at the last line. With *echo %myvariable%* or *set* without any argument you can debug the script